# Amazon S3 PHP (V2) - SignatureDoesNotMatch signed URLs

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am new to the S3 API.

We're having to use V2 of the SDK due to our hosting environment.

I can successfully upload objects into my bucket.

All files in my bucket need to be private, except I need to be able to generate a one time URL so a third party can access the file for download and then the file is deleted from the bucket.

I believed signed URLs will allow me to do this. However, I have put together the following basic code for testing and I always get a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error when trying to view the signed URL.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
  'key'    => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
  'signature' => 'v4',
  'region'=>'eu-west-1'
));

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {

  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"]);

  if($check) {

    $newFileName = time().'_'.strtolower($_FILES["theFile"]["name"]);

    // Upload an object by streaming the contents of a file
    // $pathToFile should be absolute path to a file on disk
    $result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
      'Bucket'     => 'mybucketname',
      'Key'        => $newFileName,
      'SourceFile' => $_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"],
    ));

    // We can poll the object until it is accessible
    $s3Client->waitUntil('ObjectExists', array(
      'Bucket' => 'mybucketname',
      'Key'    => $newFileName
    ));

  }

}


$iterator = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
  'Bucket' => 'mybucketname'
));

echo "<table><tr><th>Object</th><th>Plain URL</th><th>Signed URL</th></tr>";
foreach ($iterator as $object) {
  // Get a plain URL for an Amazon S3 object
  $plainUrl = $s3Client->getObjectUrl('mybucketname', $object['Key']);

  // Get a command object from the client and pass in any options
  // available in the GetObject command (e.g. ResponseContentDisposition)
  $command = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', array(
  'Bucket' => 'mybucketname',
  'Key' => $object['Key'],
   'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$object['Key'].'"'
  ));

  // Create a signed URL from the command object that will last for
  // 10 minutes from the current time
  $signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+10 minutes');

  echo "<tr><td>".$object['Key']."</td><td>".$plainUrl."</td><td>".$signedUrl."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

... upload form here
```

Given that all I wish to do is upload files and then produce a secure URL I would have thought it was fairly straight forward... but I'm confronted with the SignatureDoesNotMatch error so I must be missing a trick somewhere.

Is there anyone with S3 experience that has come across this before or can see anything obviously wrong with the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Try this without setting `ResponseContentDisposition` just to eliminate that variable from the problem, please.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have tried without `ResponseContentDisposition` - same issue!

Comment: The SignatureDoesNotMatch error should display some XML containing some debugging info.  Please edit one of those error responses into the question.  You don't need to sanitize it -- none of the data shown is considered sensitive.